# Android Google Maps Utility - onClusterClick causes NullPointerException error

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, nativescript

Writing an app in Nativescript. The following setup works fine without errors:

```
// initialize cluster manager
dis.cluster_manager = new dis.clustering.ClusterManager(app.android.context, dis.gMap);
// Instantiate the cluster manager algorithm as is done in the ClusterManager, so we can access cluster items themselves, rather than cluster markers
dis.cluster_manager_algorithm = new dis.clustering.algo.NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm();
dis.cluster_manager.setAlgorithm(dis.cluster_manager_algorithm);

var CustomClusterRenderer = dis.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer.extend({
    //constructor
    init: function () {},
    onBeforeClusterItemRendered: function (item, markerOptions) {
        console.log("onBeforeClusterItemRendered");
    },
    onBeforeClusterRendered: function (cluster, markerOptions) {
        console.log("onBeforeClusterRendered!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
});

dis.cluster_renderer = new CustomClusterRenderer(app.android.context, dis.gMap, dis.cluster_manager);
dis.cluster_renderer.setMinClusterSize(1);

dis.cluster_manager.setRenderer(dis.cluster_renderer);

dis.gMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(dis.cluster_manager);

// must be called after every unit add/remove
dis.cluster_manager.cluster();
```

Now, I want to listen to "on cluster clicks" and "on cluster item clicks". Adding the following:

```
dis.gMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(dis.cluster_manager);

dis.cluster_manager.setOnClusterClickListener(new dis.clustering.ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener({
    onClusterClick: function(cluster) {
        console.log("onClusterClick");
    }
}));

dis.cluster_manager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new dis.clustering.ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener({
    onClusterItemClick: function(item) {
        console.log("onClusterItemClick");
    }
}));
```

It compiles and runs fine, that is, when I click on the cluster marker OR cluster item marker, I get the appropriate `console.log`, but immediately after the app crashes and I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.langBoolean.booleanValue()' on a null object reference

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well great, 2 days wasted, was wondering why the hell does function in source has type boolean:

```
public interface OnClusterClickListener<T extends ClusterItem> {
   public boolean onClusterClick(Cluster<T> cluster);
}
```

As it turns out, because it's expecting a boolean. No brainer...

```
dis.cluster_manager.setOnClusterClickListener(new dis.clustering.ClusterManager.OnClusterClickListener({
    onClusterClick: function(cluster) {
        console.log("onClusterClick");
        return true;
    }
}));
```